# Updating table with static Information

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In Access I have a form that is editable via form view, but after the user clicks the save button, I want a time stamp to update the record with the User Id and Date.

I tried the following and can not seem to get it to work. 
I receive:

> Runtime error 3622 -
>  
>   You must use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordset when accessing a SQL Server table that has an IDENTITY column.

```vb
Private Sub TicketDetBUT_Save_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE MATLog " & _
    "  SET [Ticket Date] = Date() " & _
    ", [Ticket User] = GetUserName() " & _
    " Where [Load ID] = Me.TicketsDETBOX_LoadID"
End Sub
```

Again, after they click save, all of the updated information should save to the particular record, plus update the additional two fields.

Comment: Why the hell are you trying to save the data ??? Access saves it as soon as you leave the record.

Comment: Because it is there as a navigation control. It more of a Exit Button. Most of the Users I am building this solution for have never used access, so they will not know better. I do not want my users knowing that it time stamps the record with their who and when information. I want them to make what ever changes they need on the form and then when the hit the "Save and Exit button" it adds their user ID and today's Date to two columns that are hidden on the form, but are on the table.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao), you can set option to `Currentdb.Execute`.
Your code should then be

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE MATLog " & _
"  SET [Ticket Date] = Date() " & _
", [Ticket User] = GetUserName() " & _
" Where [Load ID] = Me.TicketsDETBOX_LoadID", dbSeeChanges
```

Now frankly, I did a lot of Access + SQL Server development, and I never used those disconnected forms. And my apps worked with clients installed in another country, connecting throug VPN. Just have your forms bound to linked tables, and let Access do its job.